# Translation of Fakeev's Optimal Stopping Rules for Stochastic Processes with Continuous Parameter

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, translation, paper-request

I am looking for a translation of Fakeev's "Optimal Stopping Rules for Stochastic Processes with Continuous Parameter" from 1970.

I can only find it in Russian. Does anyone know where to find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have simply tried to put ["Optimal Stopping Rules for Stochastic Processes with Continuous Parameter"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Optimal+Stopping+Rules+for+Stochastic+Processes+with+Continuous+Parameter%22) into Google. One of the first results was: http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/tvp1835

This website contains the following link:

> English version: [Theory of Probability and its Applications, 1970, 15:2, 324–331](https://doi.org/10.1137%2F1115039)

From that link you can obtain the pdf file (assuming your institution has subscription to this journal - as far as I can tell it seems to be behind a paywall).

If you try to search for ["Optimal Stopping Rules for Stochastic Processes with Continuous Parameter"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22Optimal%20Stopping%20Rules%20for%20Stochastic%20Processes%20with%20Continuous%20Parameter%22) in Google Scholar, you get [several versions of the article](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17520404902510471825). This includes both links mentioned above, but also one more [link for the English version](https://search.proquest.com/docview/915521118).